# Heteroscedasticity robust standard errors with the PLM package

Tags: r, stata, robustness, standard-error, plm

I am trying to learn R after using Stata and I must say that I love it. But now I am having some trouble. I am about to do some multiple regressions with Panel Data so I am using the `plm` package.

Now I want to have the same results with `plm` in R as when I use the `lm` function and Stata when I perform a heteroscedasticity robust and entity fixed regression.

Let's say that I have a panel dataset with the variables `Y`, `ENTITY`, `TIME`, `V1`.

I get the same standard errors in R with this code

```
lm.model<-lm(Y ~ V1 + factor(ENTITY), data=data)
coeftest(lm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(lm.model, type="HC1))
```

as when I perform this regression in Stata

```
xi: reg Y V1 i.ENTITY, robust
```

But when I perform this regression with the `plm` package I get other standard errors

```
plm.model<-plm(Y ~ V1 , index=C("ENTITY","YEAR"), model="within", effect="individual", data=data)
coeftest(plm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(plm.model, type="HC1))
```

- Have I missed setting some options?
- Does the `plm` model use some other kind of estimation and if so how?
- Can I in some way have the same standard errors with `plm` as in Stata with `, robust`

Comment: this is something you better ask at http://www.crossvalidated.com, they'll be able to help you more. And it would be nice to have some reproducible code while you're at it, together with the expected outcome. This often clears a problem up quite faster.

Comment: I don't know stata, but it looks like your stata regression is a pooled linear model of Y = a0 + a1*V1 + a2*ENTITY + epsilon with robust het se, which is what you're doing with `lm`, so the results match. In the `plm` model you're doing an FE regression Y = a0 + a1*V1 + ui + epsilon, where ui is the FE for each "individual", which by `index` you've specified to be ENTITY. So I think your stata and R results match in the first case because you're doing a pooled panel with entity as an ind var in both cases. But I don't know stata.

Answer (score 9):

By default the `plm` package does not use the *exact* same small-sample correction for panel data as Stata. However in version 1.5 of `plm` (on CRAN) you have an option that will emulate what Stata is doing.

```
plm.model<-plm(Y ~ V1 , index=C("ENTITY","YEAR"), model="within", 
    effect="individual", data=data)
coeftest(plm.model, vcov.=function(x) vcovHC(x, type="sss"))
```

This should yield the same clustered by group standard-errors as in Stata (but as mentioned in the comments, without a reproducible example and what results you expect it's harder to answer the question).

For more discussion on this and some benchmarks of R and Stata robust SEs see [Fama-MacBeth and Cluster-Robust (by Firm and Time) Standard Errors in R](http://landroni.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/fama-macbeth-and-cluster-robust-by-firm-and-time-standard-errors-in-r/).

See also:

- [Clustered standard errors in R using plm (with fixed effects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects/35812334#35812334)

Comment: `plm`'s `type="sss"` does not replicate Stata's small sample adjustment exactly because Stata has an intercept in its FE model and thus, uses a different amount of coefficients in the adjustment. `plm` does not have this intercept and, thus, uses "amount of coefficients - 1" relative to Stata in the adjustment. For small samples, this gives slightly different results but will go unnoticed in large samples.

Comment: @Helix123 Indeed. I've discussed this with the authors of `plm` and overall it is not clear what is the theoretical justification for Stata to include the intercept in these computations. While an intercept *can* be computed and `plm` does it as well if requested (`within_intercept()`, possibly still in SVN), it seems to be somewhat of an artificial concept in the context of `within` models. For now it didn't seem wise to include a "numerically exact" replicate of Stata clustered SEs... This said, Gretl seems to replicate these computations *exactly* à la Stata.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that your Stata code is different from what you are doing with plm?

`plm`'s "within" option with "individual" effects means a model of the form:

```
yit = a + Xit*B + eit + ci
```

What `plm` does is to demean the coefficients so that ci drops from the equation.

```
yit_bar = Xit_bar*B + eit_bar
```

Such that the "bar" suffix means that each variable had its mean subtracted. The mean is calculated over time and that is why the effect is for the individual. You could also have a fixed time effect that would be common to all individuals in which case the effect would be through time as well (that is irrelevant in this case though).

I am not sure what the "xi" command does in STATA, but i think it expands an interaction right ? Then it seems to me that you are trying to use a dummy variable per ENTITY as was highlighted by @richardh.

For your Stata and plm codes to match you must be using the same model.

You have two options:(1) you xtset your data in stata and use the xtreg option with the fe modifier or (2) you use plm with the pooling option and one dummy per ENTITY.

Matching Stata to R:

```
xtset entity year
xtreg y v1, fe robust
```

Matching plm to Stata:

```
plm(Y ~ V1 + as.factor(ENTITY) , index=C("ENTITY","YEAR"), model="pooling", effect="individual", data=data)
```

Then use `vcovHC` with one of the modifiers. Make sure to check this [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v11/i10/paper) that has a nice review of all the mechanics behind the "HC" options and the way they affect the variance covariance matrix.

Hope this helps.