# Clustered standard errors in R using plm (with fixed effects)

Tags: r, stata, plm, standard-error

I'm trying to run a regression in R's `plm` package with fixed effects and `model = 'within'`, while having clustered standard errors. Using the `Cigar` dataset from `plm`, I'm running:

```
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
data(Cigar)
model <- plm(price ~ sales + factor(state), model = 'within', data = Cigar)
coeftest(model, vcovHC(model, type = 'HC0', cluster = 'group'))

  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
sales  -1.21956    0.21136 -5.7701 9.84e-09
```

This is (slightly) different than what I'd get by using Stata (having written the Cigar file as a .dta):

```
use cigar

xtset state year

xtreg price sales, fe vce(cluster state)


price   Coef.   Std. Err.   t   P>t [95% Conf.  Interval]

sales   -1.219563   .2137726    -5.70   0.000   -1.650124   -.7890033
```

Namely, the standard error and T statistic are different. I've tried rerunning the R code with different "types", but none give the same result as Stata. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are looking for clustered standard errors in **three way fixed effects**, check my [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845623/6574038).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stata uses [a finite sample correction](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u20.pdf#page=53) to reduce [downwards bias](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_JHR_2015_February.pdf#page=9) in the errors due to the finite number of clusters. It is a multiplicative factor on the variance-covariance matrix, $c=\frac{G}{G-1} \cdot \frac{N-1}{N-K}$, where G is the number of groups, N is the number of observations, and K is the number of parameters. I think `coeftest` only uses $c'=\frac{N-1}{N-K}$ since if I scale R's standard error by the square of the first term in c, I get something pretty close to Stata's standard error:

```
display 0.21136*(46/(46-1))^(.5)
.21369554
```

Here's how I would replicate what Stata is doing in R:

```
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
data(Cigar)
model <- plm(price ~ sales, model = 'within', data = Cigar)
G <- length(unique(Cigar$state))
c <- G/(G - 1)
coeftest(model,c * vcovHC(model, type = "HC1", cluster = "group"))
```

This yields:

```
t test of coefficients:

       Estimate Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
sales -1.219563   0.213773 -5.70496 1.4319e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

which agrees with Stata's error of 0.2137726 and t-stat of -5.70.

This code is probably not ideal, since the number of states in the data may be different than the number of states in the regression, but I am too lazy to figure out how to get the right number of panels.

Comment: @user5450835 Please select this as the answer now that it is fixed.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/different-robust-standard-errors-of-logit-regression-in-stata-and-r/27368468#27368468

Answer (score 9):

Stata uses a specific small-sample correction that has been implemented in `plm` 1.5.

Try this:

```
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
data(Cigar)
model <- plm(price ~ sales + factor(state), model = 'within', data = Cigar)
coeftest(model, function(x) vcovHC(x, type = 'sss'))
```

Which will yield:

```
t test of coefficients:

      Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
sales  -1.2196     0.2137  -5.707 1.415e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This gives the same SE estimate up to 3 digits:

```
x <- coeftest(model, function(x) vcovHC(x, type = 'sss'))
x[ , "Std. Error"]
## [1] 0.2136951
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/different-robust-standard-errors-of-logit-regression-in-stata-and-r/27368468#27368468

Comment: @Helix123 Only partly related. While that question goes indeed into the Stata small-sample correction, it's centered around `sandwich::vcovHC` rather than `plm::vcovHC` (this question).